# How do I delete hardhat:core:config so I can create a new sample project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, smartcontracts, web3js, hardhat

I’ve been trying for hours, it won’t give me the options to create a sample project when I type “npx hardhat”

I’ve tried 1. “Mkdir hello-smart”

1. “Cd hello-smart”
2. “Npm init”
3. “Npm install hardhat”
4. “Npx hardhat”

And also tried

```
npm init -y
npm install -D hardhat
npx hardhat
```

Answer (score 0):

after you installed hardhat (npm i hardhat)

```
hardhat init
```